# Drop phone call IOS 7-8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

somebody help. How start phone call from my application:

```
NSString *phoneCallNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",_phoneNumber];
_callDuration = 0;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneCallNumber]];
```

then start timer. When timer finish i need to drop phone call. Can i do this from my application?

Comment: Can't be done (at least with public APIs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps can't do this due to the potential for malicious behaviour. The ability to initiate calls would allow your app to (for example) call a 1-900 number, and the ability to end calls would be potentially nasty as well.